# Method is not defined on the Query class

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, database-relations

I have some related models:

```
Client
id, name, user_id ++

Projects
id, title, client_id, user_id ++

Users
id, name ++
```

A client belongs to a user, and a client has many projects, and a project belongs to a client and a user.

When I try the following query to get the projects for a client, I get an error saying

`Method [projects] is not defined on the Query class.`

What does this mean?

I've tried the following queries:

```
Client::find(2)->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->projects() // Throws error
Client::where('id', '=', 2)->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->projects() // Also throwing an error
```

The following query works perfectly:

```
Client::find(2)->projects
```

My models are simple and looks like this:

```
<?php

class Client extends Eloquent
{
    public static $timestamps = TRUE;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Project');
    }
}

class Project extends Eloquent
{
    public static $timestamps = TRUE;

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('Client');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent
{
    public static $timestamps = TRUE;

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Client');
    }

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Project');
    }
}
```

Why won't it work when I use where clauses? It works when I don't use where clauses, but I need to filter projects and clients on user_id as well. (My plan is to allow multiple users connected to a company to see all their projects and clients.)

Comment: Maybe it's because method 'where' returns some new instance of class Query, not $this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually not retrieving anything from the query, just add `first()` or add `get()` then loop and call your `projects()`.

Should work like this:

```
Client::where('id', '=', 2)->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first()->projects()
```

And according to your comment, it should work too for single row:

```
Client::find(2)->projects()->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
```

Comment: I got another answer from the Laravel forums: `Client::find(2)->projects()->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)` Which one would be the most effective?